# How can I integrate salesforce databse with hybrid app?

Tags: api, salesforce, hybrid-mobile-app

Integration is possible in native apps. But how do I use it for hybrid apps?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Heroku Connect](https://www.heroku.com/connect) to syncronize your data between Salesforce and a Heroku Postgre database, and in turn use the Postgre database to power a Heroku hybrid or mobile app.

You can also use the Salesforce Mobile SDK to access your Salesforce data in a mobile app: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Mobile_SDK